# Why do we need to do a PLU decomposition? Isn't an LU one sufficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

And also, how does one go about doing a PLU decomp?

Thanks

Comment: Not all non singular matrices have a $LU$ factorisation. However, all non singular matrices have a partial pivot LU factorisation $PA = LU$. There is also a full (or complete) LU factorisation $PAQ =LU$.

Answer (score 5):

$ LU $ decomposition encodes gaussian elimination without pivoting. $ PA = LU $ encodes gaussian elimination with pivoting, which is crucial for numerical stability (and also sometimes pivoting is used to obtain sparser $ L, U $ factors).